# Android netrunner: may I trash a card before I am forced to discard?

Tags: android-netrunner

As a runner, if I am tagged and the corp spends a click to destroy a resource of mine, if the resource can be trashed for some good, may I trash it before it gets discarded?

(as an example of such a resource: Tallie Perrault)

Answer (score 4):

No because, unlike magic, Netrunner doesn't have a stack. Situations resolve in order the based on who's turn it is. If the corp spends a click to trash your resource you cannot "as a response" trash the resource for its ability. It is the corps turn so their click goes through first and by the time a paid ability window gets around for you to use the ability your resource is already gone.

Edit: As Andrew mentioned in the comments, there is one exception to this. Cards that have prevent or avoid as a "keyword" (most of these are related to damage and/or tags) CAN be used as a response.

Comment: It might be worth a special call out about "prevent" paid abilities, which are used in response to something the other player is doing, and not during a paid ability window.

Comment: I think one other important distinction is that there is a paid ability window between clicks. So if on the corps turn click 1 the corp plays SEA source to tag the runner, between clicks 1 and 2 each player may use paid abilities. You may trash your resources using their paid abilities in this window. 

You cannot use your trash ability in response to being tagged, but you may use it between the click you are tagged and the click that could be used to trash the resource.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Runner may not voluntarily trash Resources or Hardware, but may be required (or permitted) to do so via other card effects (e.g. Aesop's Pawnshop).

The only cards the Runner can trash voluntarily are programs:

> The Runner can choose to trash any number of his installed programs at the beginning of an > install program action.

Comment: The card in question has an ability whose cost is to trash the card, so the normal rule about not voluntarily trashing resources would seem to be overridden in this case.